# Como pegar um valor digitado em form e passar pra url no iframe?

Tags: formulário, input

Algo assim:

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Código de rastreio" title="Código de rastreio">
<button type="submit" id="bto">Rastrear</button>
</form>
  
<iframe src="https://link.com/ +valor digitado no input"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em caso de você não precisar dar `submit` em uma action em seu formulário, é possível realizar isso criando uma função que será chamada no lugar do submit deste formulário e que irá adicionar o valor do input de ID "iframe" como `src` do `iframe` de ID "iframe":

```html
<form onsubmit="setLink();return false">
<input type="text" placeholder="Código de rastreio" id="input" title="Código de rastreio">
<button type="submit" id="bto">Rastrear</button>
</form>  

<iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>  

<script>
  function setLink() {
    let iframe = document.getElementById("iframe")
    let input = document.getElementById("input")
    let inputText = input.value
    iframe.src = "https://link.com/" + inputText 
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, ficou como eu esperava, obrigado!